# Undo my merge commit that has cause work lost on branch I was merging to

Tags: git, git-reset

This morning I did a merge commit of my feature branch into the main dev branch but when doing so *I forgot to update the dev branch that had several commits and merge commits from other people on it*.

So when I did my merge commit I was asked if I wanted to simply Merge or Rebase (With a warning that rebasing could cause issues) so I opted for a merge.

All seemingly was fine but after pushing the merge to remote I found out that work for others had been lost.

Note: My Merge commit is publish/pushed and the other developers have pulled the dev branch since. No new work committed since my one.

Am I correct in thinking that if I run `git reset --hard 660df8da` where 660df8da is the last merge-commit on the dev branch by a colleague which is where I want to get to so that I can re do my merge commit correctly?

Below is the outline of the git system as it currently stands, the red line is my branch.

[image]

Comment: Question: Have you already pushed your branch to the remote since you pushed, and, if so, is there _any_ chance that someone else may have already pulled?

Comment: The Branch is on remote yes, as to wether someone else has pulled, I am unsure but would assume yes as two other people are doing work and commiting as they complete small jobs

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No new commits to the dev branch since my last merge commit either

Comment: If you don't care about losing/nuking commits, then yes, doing a hard reset to the correct previous commit should put you in the position you want.